# What does -> mean in OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal

When I run `ls` command on MacOS I see the line which contains a `->` symbol. I cannot find a way to describe it.

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root             wheel       21 Feb 18  2014 libBSDPClient.dylib -> libBSDPClient.A.dylib
```

What does it mean? And how can I call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->` in the output of `ls` indicates a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (aka soft link).  The part on the left is the name of the symlink, and the part on the right is its target.  So in your example:

libBSDPClient.dylib -> libBSDPClient.A.dylib

There is a "file" `libBSDPClient.dylib` which is a link to `libBSDPClient.A.dylib` (in the same directory, and which may not actually exist).

As for your question about how to "call" it, well, you don't "call" shared objects, but you can "load" them in a running program by the usual mechanisms, such as runtime dynamic linking or explicitly via [`dlopen()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html).